# Python Function should return CSS code

Tags: html, css, python-3.x

I have modify the \to_html" function of the simple server given in Appendix A, so that it returns this CSS code: This css code print's a text in a box with green margins.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        div.ex
        {
        width:220px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid green;
        margin:0px;
        background-color: #778899;
        }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>

        <p><i><center><div class="ex">It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were stricking thirhteen.</div></center><i></p>

        </body>
        </html>.
```

With this modied \to_html" function in place, the command:

```
    telnet localhost 8888
```

should produce output of the form

```
    <html>...2013-10-29 15:57:00.343224...</html>
```

This is the Appendix A:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import *
from socket import *
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8888

def to_html(t) :
    result = t
    return result

def to_http(h) :
    result = h
    return result

def worker(sck) :
    t = str(datetime.now())
    # sck.send(to_http(to_html(t))) # Python 2.X
    sck.send(bytes(to_http(to_html(t)), "UTF-8")) # Python 3.X
    sck.close()

ssck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ssck.bind((HOST, PORT))
ssck.listen(1)
while True :
    sck, addr = ssck.accept()
    worker(sck)
```

Now my question how do I do all this? The server provides the time of the day.

Comment: Please make sparing use of titles!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I have to edit the to_html function in the Appendix A so that it prints in the browser the CSS code. And I have no ideea how to do that.

Comment: So you are trying to create a server in PHP?

Comment: No,I just want to display the html code using Python.

Comment: How is the Python code called?

Comment: telnet localhost 8888 to print the time

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your code.  You should double check that it is correct.